# Utilizar Ace.js para un autocompletador de texto, pero cambiando sus Id y class

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito poder implementar el editor ace.js dentro de mi proyecto para completarlo al 100%, pero no tengo forma, ya que los archivos del ace por defecto traen consigo una serie de id, class y crea elementos que entra en conflicto con todo mi proyecto. Hasta ahora he logrado salvar parte de la funcionalidad, pero le falta un empujón que no se interpretar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es la captura de pantalla del Browser con el servidor en localhost funcionando. Todas las pruebas salen correctas excepto el autocompletador.

Pongo aquí el código de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación pondré el script correspondiente del documento html:

```
/*Los src, no tienen mucho misterio*/

    <script src="src/ace.js"></script>
    <script src="src/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
```

```
/*El section, lugar donde se va a editar, siendo
div#editor el lugar donde se va a escribir todo autocompletado
y siendo pre#aut_editor el lugar donde se escribirá para autocompletarse*/

<section>
  <div class="bx">

    <div id="editor"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>

    <div >
            <pre id="aut_editor"></pre>
        </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

A continuación, el script incrustado en el html para hacer funcionar ace:

```
function triggerEvent(el, eventName, options) {
  var event;
  if (window.CustomEvent) {
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, options);
  } else {
    event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    event.initCustomEvent(eventName, true, true, options);
  }
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
}

  var dl = document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor");
  
    ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var editor = ace.edit("aut_editor");
  
  editor.getSession().setValue( dl.value );
  
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/cssv");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/iPlastic");
    // enable autocompletion and snippets
  
  
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    useWorker: false
    });
  editor.getSession().on( 'change' , function( e ) {
    dl.value = editor.getSession().getValue() ;
    triggerEvent(dl, 'change', {
        detail: 'Display on trigger...'
    });
    
    //dl.val( editor.getSession().getValue() ).trigger( 'change' );
  });
```

Esta parte entiendo que está correcta, ya que no proporciona ningún tipo de fallo, pero es necesaria para entender los errores, o al menos, eso creo, ahora pondré de dónde CREO que viene el error:

En el archivo `src/ace.js`, en la línea 2.636 concretamente, se hace alusión a crear un `textarea` para recrear todo el contenido del `pre#aut_editor`, cosa que no me interesa, ya que yo quiero verlo directamente en el área correspondiente, siendo esta `div#editor`, por tanto entiendo que no debería crear un elemento textarea, sino coger el propio div, con su id, pero haciendo las pruebas, no lo consigue leer.
La primera pregunta viene aquí, ¿Cómo consigo hacer eso?

```
    var text = dom.createElement("textarea");
    text.className = "ace_text-input";
```

Expuesto esto, quizá no venga de ahí el problema y yo me esté comiendo demasiado la cabeza, así que dejaré los fragmentos correspondientes a los errores que proporciona el Browser en orden de salida (ya que yo no se interpretarlos correctamente, ya que estoy empezando con javascript):

```
    this.$detectNewLine = function(text) {
        var match = text.match(/^.*?(\r\n|\r|\n)/m);
        this.$autoNewLine = match ? match[1] : "\n";
        this._signal("changeNewLineMode");
    };
```

```
    this.insert = function(position, text) {
        if (this.getLength() <= 1)
            this.$detectNewLine(text);
        
        return this.insertMergedLines(position, this.$split(text));
    };
```

```
    oop.implement(this, EventEmitter);
    this.setValue = function(text) {
        var len = this.getLength() - 1;
        this.remove(new Range(0, 0, len, this.getLine(len).length));
        this.insert({row: 0, column: 0}, text);
    };
```

```
    this.setValue = function(text) {
        this.doc.setValue(text);
        this.selection.moveTo(0, 0);

        this.$resetRowCache(0);
        this.setUndoManager(this.$undoManager);
        this.getUndoManager().reset();
    };
```

**Muchas gracias de antebrazo**

**[EDIT]**

Aquí tengo subidos los archivos en GitHub, donde se pueden copiar y trabajar con ellos de forma sencilla. Hice también el README, comentando los fallos que tiene y lo que me gustaría hacer, pero creo que si se ve, es más fácil de saber lo que necesito conseguir: [GitHub](https://github.com/Aaronibio/collabtext)

Comment: Tu problema es complejo de reproducir. Lo que estás queriendo hacer, básicamente, ¿es combinar _quill editor_ con _ace_? (por eso lo del cambio de id y clases)

Comment: Si, efecticamente eso mismo, y el problema viene de que ace.js crea un textarea, pero eso no me interesa, ya que el textarea no tengo forma de hacerlo colaborativo, por tanto, necesito unir ambos elementos de forma que no cree conflicto. Subiré los archivos a Github? será buena idea?

Comment: Lo de crear un repositorio en GH queda a tu criterio :) Si es posible, procura adjuntar un [mcve] editando tu pregunta, especificando además _en qué sección del html estás colocando los scripts_ (antes de cerrar el body, al inicio del body, etc.)

Comment: ¿`dom` se definió previamente por ti o por alguna de las librerías usadas? De lo contrario, aquí hay un error `var text = dom.createElement("textarea");`

Comment: el dom se creo por una de las librerías usadas, es lo que entiendo que usa para crear el textarea dentro del <pre>. Pero no estoy seguro tampoco. Editaré el código, lo llenaré de comentarios y lo pondré en GitHub :3